# Group of people on a boat being killed off by a slimy thing

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie on TV many many moons ago, where a group of people were on a boat, in very calm water (a lagoon) and were being killed off, one at a time. The perpetrator was some slimy thing from below the surface that left tell-tale seaweed and green slime footprints (obviously stamped with a plumber's friend). It was very camp, at least I found it grossly so.

Does anyone know what this "classic" was?

Comment: Hmmm. They green slime footprints threw me off; otherwise it could have been Stephen King's ["The Raft"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Raft_(short_story)), adapted for TV as one of the stories in "Creepshow 2". In that story, there is a monster that looks like an oil slick, killing people stranded in the middle of a lake. Alas! Since it has no humanoid form, it cannot leave footprints of any kind.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds to me like one of the vignettes from [Creepshow 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092796/), which featured a group of teenagers on a raft/pontoon in the middle of a lake or lagoon.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [The Creature From the Black Lagoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creature_from_the_Black_Lagoon), possibly? It's in black&white, though the poster shows the creature to be green.

Comment: I don't think The Creature left suction cup (plumber's friend) footprints; but I admit that movie is what immediately came to mind after reading the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the scenes from the "movie" is a person being sucked through the top part of a floating deck (between the boards) then what you are thinking of is definitely the Raft.